# how to convert my base64string to bitmap in windows phone?

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, base64, arrays

I want to convert base64string to bitmap and i m doing below method but its not working.

```
   public static BitmapImage base64image(string s)
        {
            if (s.Length > 0)
            {
                byte[] fileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(s.Trim('\0'));
              // byte[] fileBytes = new byte[s.Length * sizeof(char)];
              //System.Buffer.BlockCopy(s.ToCharArray(), 0, fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length))
                {
                    ms.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();                                       
                    bitmapImage.SetSource(ms);
                    return bitmapImage;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }

        }
```

my base64 string is

```
string s="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"
```

But it gives an exception like **"The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters."**

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void ConvertThis(string ImageText)
{
   if (ImageText.Length > 0)
   {
      Byte[] bitmapData = new Byte[ImageText.Length];
      bitmapData = Convert.FromBase64String(FixBase64ForImage(ImageText));
      System.IO.MemoryStream streamBitmap = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bitmapData);
      Bitmap bitImage = new Bitmap((Bitmap)Image.FromStream(streamBitmap));
   }
}

public string FixBase64ForImage(string Image)
{
   System.Text.StringBuilder sbText = new System.Text.StringBuilder(Image,Image.Length);
   sbText.Replace("\r\n", String.Empty);
   sbText.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
   return sbText.ToString();
}
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks i got solution from FixBase64ForImage(string Image) function ...thanks lot